# Duda con PySimpleGUI

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy aprendiendo PySimpleGUI y tengo dudas con un script que estoy haciendo, sobre un formulario de registro.

Mi duda está en los `elif` que hay en el bucle `while`. Lo que quiero hacer es que para registrarse ambos campos (`Nombre de usuario` y `Contraseña`) deben tener información. Intenté usar algunos `elif` en caso de que sólo se completara un campo o no se completara ninguno, pero sólo funciona el primer `elif`.

Aquí dejo mi script:

```
import PySimpleGUI as psg

layout = [
    [psg.Text("Nombre de usuario:"), psg.InputText()],
    [psg.Text("Contraseña:"), psg.InputText(password_char = "*")],
    [psg.Button("Crear cuenta"), psg.Button("Cancelar")]
]

window = psg.Window("Practica", layout, element_justification= "right")

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == psg.WIN_CLOSED or event == "Cancelar":
        break
    elif values[0] or values[1] == "":
        print("Ingrese información en el campo restante.")
    elif values[0] and values[1] == "":
        print("Ingrese información en ambos campos.")
    elif values[0] and values[1] == True:
        print(f"Gracias por registrarte, {values[0]}.")

window.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Al menos, tal y como lo has puesto, la primera condición

```
values[0]
```

es condición necesaria en el segundo elif, mientras que en el primer elif es suficiente. Luego si se ejecutase la segunda, necesariamente se tendría que ejecutar la primera.

```
if a or b: print("a es suficiente")
elif a and b: print("a es necesario")
```

Mi recomendación: Invertir el orden.

**Cuidado.** En caso de no rellenar el usuario, el evento te devuelve `''`, que para un if, es interpretado como `True`. Haz la prueba. Trata de meter solo la contraseña, pero no el usuario.

Lo he modificado un poco, dado que trabaja con strings. Ahi te va, espero que te sea de utilidad.

```
if event == psg.WIN_CLOSED or event == "Cancelar":
    break
elif values[0]+values[1] == "":
    print("Ingrese información en ambos campos.")
elif values[0]=="" or values[1] == "":
    print("Ingrese información en el campo restante.")
# else:
elif values[0]!= "" and values[1]!="": 
    print(f"Gracias por registrarte, {values[0]}.")
```